# What is it called when a subclass changes the implementation of a superclass method?

Tags: java

I would search for this on my own, but I don't even know where to look. Is there an annotation for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overriding. And [`@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) is the annotation, from the link

> Indicates that a method declaration is intended to override a method declaration in a supertype.

Comment: imho I thing this should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @YazanWYusuf It directly answers the question, and I'm not soliciting additional information **or** suggesting improvements. Why should it be a comment?

Comment: @YazanWYusuf Question seeks this answer.